# Shorten link in views

Tags: views, 8

I  have a Drupal 8 website with  [Shorten](https://www.drupal.org/project/shorten)   producing short links to content. "Tokens" and "Record Shorten" module are installated as well.

I've like then to build a view exposing a text like "Hey,  the shorten link for the current node is {{ current_node_shorten_link }}"

How can I achieve this?

Comment: can you please post your code otherwise screen shots?

Comment: You need to have the `Record Shortened URLs` submodule enabled. Then you can create Views the usual way. Have you reached that stage yet? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: thanks @prkon, Documentation actually requires  to install  RSUrls. I had no luck with that though. My "content" View has no field realted to the "Shorten" module.